# Firebase: how to get data

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

i am new to firebase, i want to get data of groups of all users like users/uid/groups

below image shows my database structure, i want to get 'groups' of all users.

[image]

i have get the users by this but unable to get groups.

my code is here of get users

```
  db.ref('users').on('value', dataSnapshot => {
    var users = [];
    dataSnapshot.forEach(child => {
        users.push({
            name: child.val().name,
            key: child.key,
          });
        console.log('users', child.val());
    });
  });
```

but i want to to get all groups of all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't exactly clear what challenge you are having, but if you just want to create list of all the groups like you are with users, then this should do it (this just drops the value of the Groups object there, if you need the key too, then modify appropriately):

```js
firebase.database().ref('users').on('value', dataSnapshot => {
  var users = [];
  var groups = [];
  dataSnapshot.forEach(child => {
    users.push({
      name: child.val().name,
      key: child.key,
    });
    if (child.val().Groups) {
      Object.keys(child.val().Groups).forEach(key => {
        groups.push(child.val().Groups[key])
      });
    }
    console.log('users', child.val());
  });
  console.log(groups);
});
```